# How configure PostgreSQL portable on Django settings file

Tags: django, postgresql

I would like to configure PostgreSQL portable (on a USB key) to Django using the settings.py file but I don't know what to insert in the HOST parameter.

Comment: Is it not `localhost`?

Comment: It's how you suggest me. it happened that having very little experience with django that I attributed the responsibility to the database setup, instead it was a postgresql problem that I solved. Thank you